# Tell me whats wrong with this python code?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to coding so please help me out here. The code will only run until the 5th line. This code may be a total babel, but please humor me.

EDIT: There is no exception, nothing happens. After asking me to choose between 1 and 2, the code just stops.

```
print('This program will tell you the area some shapes')
print('You can choose between...')
print('1. rectangle')
print('or')
print('2. triangle')

def shape():
    shape = int(input('What shape do you choose?'))

    if shape == 1: rectangle
    elif shape == 2: triangle
    else: print('ERROR: select either rectangle or triangle')

def rectangle():
    l = int(input('What is the length?'))
    w = int(input('What is the width?'))
    areaR=l*w
    print('The are is...')
    print(areaR)

def triangle():
    b = int(input('What is the base?'))
    h = int(input('What is the height?'))
    first=b*h
    areaT=.5*first
    print('The area is...')
    print(areaT)
```

Comment: Post the exception or unexpected result you get when you ask questions. "It runs to the 5th line then does nothing and exits", for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better coding style will be putting everything inside functions:

```
def display():
    print('This program will tell you the area some shapes')
    print('You can choose between...')
    print('1. rectangle')
    print('or')
    print('2. triangle')

def shape():
    shap = int(input('What shape do you choose?'))
    if shap == 1: rectangle()
    elif shap == 2: triangle()
    else:
        print('ERROR: select either rectangle or triangle')
        shape()


def rectangle():
    l = int(input('What is the length?'))
    w = int(input('What is the width?'))
    areaR=l*w
    print('The are is...')
    print(areaR)


def triangle():
    b = int(input('What is the base?'))
    h = int(input('What is the height?'))
    first=b*h
    areaT=.5*first
    print('The area is...')
    print(areaT)

if __name__=="__main__":
    display() #cal display to execute it 
    shape() #cal shape to execute it
```

Comment: I disagree, if you are only calling something once (and can't foresee using it again), then there is no need to put it in a function.

Comment: Well, you generally only want to put things in the module definition that really are _only_ run once.

Comment: @Lattyware even if we are calling something once,say `display()` here,  but we're able to control it's execution, we can execute it wherever we want.On the other hand a top-level code is executed from top to bottom and we can't control it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes we can, we simply place the code where we want it to execute.

Comment: @acattle I did ,scroll down to `if __name__=="__main__":`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ashwini, I understand now. However, what are the last 3 lines for? Sorry for my dilettante nature, this program is actually named "experiment.py" in my folder.

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57 `if __name__=="__main__"` is used to check whether the file is run directly or is imported as a module, so my version of code will not call any function if it is imported as a module, but if you run it directly in IDE then `__name__=="__main__"` condition becomes true, and the code is executed normally.

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57 the variable `__name__` is equal to `"__main__"` if the file is executed directly.

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is that you have put your code into functions, but never call them.

When you define a function:

```
def shape():
    ...
```

To run that code, you then need to call the function:

```
shape()
```

Note that Python runs code in order - so you need to define the function before you call it.

Also note that to call a function you always need the brackets, even if you are not passing any arguments, so:

```
if shape == 1: rectangle
```

Will do nothing. You want `rectangle()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused. How would I call "shape()" and what would I need to change in order to implement "rectangle()"?

Comment: you also don't need to put int() around input(). input() already returns a number.

Comment: Yes, so how do I make it so that when "1" or "2" are inputted, their respective functions are called?

Comment: @lciamp That's only true in 2.x, not in 3.x

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57 You call a function by following it's name with brackets, potentially containing any arguments. If you don't know how to call a function, I suggest you go and reads a Python tutorial before trying to write more code - it's basic stuff.

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57 you need to make 3 changes: 1) your "choose between 1 and 2" code shoulc come AFTER you define your functions. 2) you need to call your functions. they will not run unless you call them. In your case, after you `print('2. rectangle')` line, put `shape()` to call your `shape` function. 3) add `()` to your `rectangle` and `triangle` calls

Comment: @acattle rectangle/triangle only need to be defined when shape() is called, not when it is defined and `def` does not evaluate

Comment: @tcaswell by "choose between 1 and 2" code, I was refering to everything above the line `def shape():`.

Comment: @acattle ah, I thought you meant the logic.